# Table Relationship - Best Practice

Tags: sql-server, database, relational-database

If I have 3 tables

Table_A

```
Id
Name
```

Table_B

```
Id
Fk_A_Id
Name
```

Table_C

```
Id
Fk_A_Id
Fk_B_Id
Name
```

Question: Is it best practice to have `Table_A` `Id` in `Table_C` since we already have  `Table_B` in `Table_C` and `Table_B` has `Table_A` `Id`?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether the association `(Fk_B_Id, Fk_A_Id)` in Table_C is redundant (i.e. identical to or a subset of `(Id, Fk_A_Id)` in Table_B), and how consistency is maintained in the database. If they're the same, then `Fk_A_Id` in Table_C can logically be dropped.

For example, if we're modeling a strict containment hierarchy, e.g. every city belongs to one state, and every state belongs to one country, then it's logically redundant to record a city's country directly.

But consider a situation where equipment is used by a team, and a team has one manager, but each equipment can have its own manager which isn't necessarily the same as the team manager. In this case, we have independent facts which need to be recorded separately.

Redundant attributes are often used for performance optimizations. The problem with recording the same fact twice is that multiple instances of the same thing can become inconsistent. If consistency is maintained somehow, then there's no logical problem with redundancy.

I would recommend going for a normalized and non-redundant model first, and only add redundancy when performance is a problem and simpler approaches to optimize haven't been effective.

Answer (score 0):

I would not think it is best practice to have both A and B's ID in Table C since all the IDs would be present when joined together in a query.  I think it also depends on how the data is organized in the different tables and how they relate together.  If Table A is customers, and B is addresses, while C is phone numbers (for the sake of saying) I would only have the A ID in B and C to relate back to the customer table.

That being said, most software I've run across such as Magento will relate A->B, then B->C, then C->D... and so on and will never have any IDs from previous tables.

Comment: What if the 3 tables are Country, State and City?

Comment: If those were the tables, it would make more sense to then do the A->B, B->C referencing because you'd be going from 1 to many in each relation.  But I still wouldn't put the Country ID in the City table, because the City would relate to the State.

Even if you had duplicate City names, they would just refer to the parent State, which would then refer to the parent Country.